# How to resolve the Error "Call to a member function getChildren() on null"

Tags: layered-navigation, sidebar, submenu

I wish to display the `level1` and `level2` subcategories of current `active` category in layered navigation in list page. So I gave the below code in `catalog/category/view.phtml` :

```
 <div class="sidebar-block">
<?php
$html = '';

$children = $menuTree->getChildren();
$parentLevel = $menuTree->getLevel();
$childLevel = is_null($parentLevel) ? 0 : $parentLevel + 1;

$counter = 1;
$childrenCount = $children->count();
$category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
$categories = $category->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
 ?>
    <div class="block-content clearfix">
        <ul class="subcategories">
            <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
        <?php


foreach ($children as $child) {
    $child->setLevel($childLevel);
    $child->setIsFirst($counter == 1);
    $child->setIsLast($counter == $childrenCount);
    $child->setPositionClass($itemPositionClassPrefix . $counter);

    $outermostClassCode = 'level'. $childLevel;
    $_hasChildren = ($child->hasChildren()) ? 'has-children' : '';

    $html .= '<li '. $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) .'>';

    $html .= '<a href="'. $child->getUrl() .'" class="'. $outermostClassCode .' '. $_hasChildren .'">'. $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName())) .'</a>';

    if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
        $html .= '<div class="'. $childrenWrapClass .'">';
    }

    $nextChildLevel = $childLevel + 1;

    if (!empty($_hasChildren)) {
        $html .= '<ul class="level'. $childLevel .'">';
        $html .=     $this->render($child, $childrenWrapClass);
        $html .= '</ul>';
    }

    if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
        $html .= '</div>';
    }

    $html .= '</li>';

    $counter++;
} ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

am getting the error like `Call to a member function getChildren() on null` 
How to resolve this? What should be done.Or is this approach wrong? Help please. am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If error says that you call function on null, first thing I would do is to check variable `$category` or  `$menuTree` with `print_r()` or `var_dump` - maybe they are in fact null, which means the objects which should be under these varaibles or you think they should be, in fact are not assigned to them. Later if you detect which and if varaible is empty you should figure out way and then you can perform some changes in your code to get what you've planned.

Comment: can you suggest a way to display level 1 and level 2 category in layered navigation in list page?

Comment: I am not actually working on Magento 1, I don't have it even installed in raw copy, so I cannot help you now. I am sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this -

```
if($category->hasChildren()){
    $categories = $category->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
}
```